# Purpose of use classname; inside a class

Tags: php, laravel

I've seen in laravel framework Some of the classes have use Classname; inside a class like Auth class, so I need to know, what is the purpose of using use Classname; inside a class while it can be used outside a class as well.

For e.g

```
//e.g of auth class
class AuthController extends Controller {
     use Authenticable;   //or some other class
}
```

Can't we use it like

```
use Authenticable;   //or some other class
class AuthController extends Controller {

}
```

is there any difference among those two above ?

Comment: Look at this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 3):

When a `use` statement is used in the header of a class, it's [doing class/namespace import](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

When a `use` statement is used within a class, it's [using a trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

They are not interchangable. You usually import a class/namespace from another PHP class using the header `use`, then if it's a trait that can be mixed with your class, you do the internal `use` to use that trait.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about trait, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here use is using to include traits in our classes. Inside the classes, we can include multiple traits by comma separated. 

//e.g of auth class
    class AuthController extends Controller {
         use Authenticable;   //or some other class
    }

Here use is using to include namespaces in our files.

use Authenticable;   //or some other class
class AuthController extends Controller {

}
```

Please go through following links:

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-traits-in-php-5-4/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/namespacing-in-php--net-27203